# Static assertion to check if a variable name is defined in the current scope

Tags: c, gcc

I am defining a macro like the following and my goal is to complete the `TODO`.

```
#define TEST(_expr, args...) \
    do { \
        // TODO _Static_assert to make sure __xyz is not declared \
        int __xyz = _expr; \
        if (__xyz < 0) { \
            // do some error handling stuff utilizing args and __xyz \
        } \
    } while (0)
```

Macro runs `_expr` (usually a function call) and does some error handling stuff in the case of failure. the stuff done utilize `__xyz` and `args...`. The corner case is that the developer using this macro might have the variable `__xyz` defined on a higher scope and pass it as one of the `args...`. Here is an example.

```
int foo(void);
int bar() {
    int __xyz;
    // .... some lines of code
    TEST(foo(), x, y, z, __xyz);
    // .... some more lines of code
    return 0;
}
```

In this example, there would be a silent issue. I want to use `_Static_assert` to make sure that no variable `__xyz` is defined in any of the parent scopes. basically the macro `TEST` would cause a compile-time error at the above function because `__xyz` is defined at the beginning of the scope.

- Is this doable? If so how?
- If it is not doable how can I avoid such a corner case?

Theoretically, this should be possible because whether some word is declared/defined at some line is compile-time information.

Thank you all in advance!!

Comment: why do you need this? isn't `do { ... }` a separate scope, where you declare `__xyz`?

Comment: @user3365922 it is a separate scope. If the developer uses this macro to with `__xyz` defined on parent scope, there will not be a compile error. The issue is not that I don't want the error. The issue is that I want an error! In the given example, the variable `__xyz` will be used by `error handling stuff` portion. BUT that will not be a reference to the `__xyz` defined at the beginning `bar`. It would be a reference to `__xyz` declared in `TEST` macro. which is the silent failure that I was talking about...

Comment: @user3365922 Yes, which is the problem. The author of `bar` intends `__xyz` to refer to the `__xyz` in `bar`, but when a macro pastes in its arguments, `__xyz` will end up referring to the one from the macro instead.

Comment: Don't use identifiers with double underscores or beginning with an underscore! They are reserved names for the compiler and its associated libraries.

Comment: @aschepler I'll keep that in mind but that is besides the point. Bad coding practices might cause this issue. I don't have control over that.

Comment: Not sure if there's a way to do exactly what you're asking. You can of course use a name which more obviously should not be used, like `PRIVATE_VAR_OF_MACRO_TEST` (protect from Murphy, not from Machiavelli). Or maybe if you explain the reasons the macro can't be a function, there would be other ways to deal with those reasons.

Comment: @aschepler `PRIVATE_VAR_OF_MACRO_TEST` definitely reduces the probability. tho not solves the problem. There are multiple reasons that I am using the macro. One of them is that I need the `__LINE__` and `__FUCNTION__` from the call . in this example `bar`

Comment: Do not use `__xyz`, identifiers with leading double underscores is a reserved identifier. In my macros I use the upper and lower characters like `int _uPpEr_LoWeR_cAsE`. I believe checking if a identifier is defined is impossible - in case it's not defined, the token does not exists. You can also use `int xyz##__LINE__;`

Comment: The `__LINE__` issue can be worked around by `#define TEST(expr, args) test_func(expr, args, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)` and then having `test_func` be an (inline?) function which takes two extra arguments.

Comment: Of course at some level you have to document your requirements and trust the user to follow them.  A really perverse user can always find some way to misuse your code.  You can't stop them; you can only make it clear that it is their fault, not yours, that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although @aschepler's comment is practically adequate, it is not technically bulletproof. The OCD in me came up with this answer. We can use -Wshadow and treat it as an error in the macro

```c
#define TEST(_expr, args...) \
    do { \
        _Pragma(GCC diagnostic push) \
        _Pragma(GCC diagnostic error "-Wshadow") \
        int TEST_MACRO_PV_xyz = _expr; \
        _Pragma(GCC diagnostic pop) \
        if (TEST_MACRO_PV_xyz < 0) { \
             handle_and_propagate_error(TEST_MACRO_PV_xyz, ##args); \
        } \
    } while (0)
```

Note that for different compilers and different versions you need to enable/disable this error differently.